# running two scenario at same time with loadrunner

Tags: testing, automation, load-testing, loadrunner

Can we run two scenarios at same time with loadrunner?

E.g. Suppose there are 50 user and I have to generate script such that 25 user accessing login and order modules and other 25 user just browsing the site.
Is it possible to generate such scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running multiple scenarios at the same time (assuming standalone controller) is not possible on THE SAME controller at THE SAME time.

From your description of the problem **I assume you are looking for multiple scripts (groups) running in the same scenario - if so then the answer is YES**.

In the controller you add more Groups (scripts are called groups in controller) and define the number of vusers or % of total vusers (depending on scenario type & controller version) for the group. I have not seen any limit on the number of groups/scenario. I've never needed more than 15 groups in a single scenario thou ..

Answer (score 1):

Rohit,

I have a direct question for you, are you using an evaluation license?

Generally you would just use a 50 user license with two groups of 25 users apiece.   The only time I get this question for the past 15 years is when someone is trying to combine result sets for two 25 user evaluation license copies of a LoadRunner controller.

Answer (score 1):

Rohit, you can create two seperate scripts - one for your login & other for browse site transactions. In controller scenario , you can select select by Group and add these two scripts in your groups and assign 25 vusers each to both.